any USA polling on what if presidential/congressional election were ranked-choice voting
A lot of people who are dissatisfied with the American political system have suggested ranked-choice voting.
I cannot find any polling where the people are asked, "What if the presidential or congressional election were done by ranked-choice voting: what would be your vote?" Do you know of any?
This would be curious. I find it hard to believe that no political science department in the whole of the USA took the trouble of attempting to find out.
edit: same question applies to STAR voting, or proportional representation, or other methods

Presidential elections using proportional representation might prove a trifle difficult to arrange. Unless you intend to keep the electoral college, I guess.

It's difficult to ask people in a meaningful way what their vote would be since the point of introducing ranked-choice voting would be to change the way ballots would look: there would be more candidates.  How do I know who I would vote for if I don't know what the ballot would look like?

@phoog for example they could ask about Biden, Trump, RFK Jr, Jill Stein and Chase Oliver.
